# Python: include library folder when running from command line

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a directory structure:

```
root_dir
 ├── src
 │   └── p1.py
 └── lib
     ├── __init__.py
     ├── util1.py
     └── util2.py
```

I want to run `src/p1.py` which uses `lib/util1.py` using an import statement `import lib.util1 as u1`.

It runs fine when I use PyCharm, but I want to also run it from command line. How can I run the program from command line?

I have tried `cd root_dir` then `python src/p1.py`.

But it produces the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./src/p1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import lib.util1 as u1
ImportError: No module named lib.util1
```

How can I run the python program `src/p1.py` from the command line?

Edit: Based on the suggestion from @Sumedh Junghare, in comments, I have added `__init__.py` in lib folder. But still it produces the same error!

Comment: @warl0ck This also produces same error.

Comment: you can make `lib` a python package by adding `__init__.py` in this directory. Then you can use import statement as usual.

Comment: What about: `PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:. python src/p1.py` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the following steps

1. Add `__init__.py` at lib folder.

Add this line at p1.py file on top

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../') 
import lib.util1 as u1
```

Run the p1.py file from src dir. Hope it will work.

Edit:

If you do not want to add `sys.path.append('../')`, set PYTHONPATH in env-var from this resource.
[How to add to the pythonpath in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows)

Comment: I have seen similar solutions on Stackoverflow. But I don't want to change the source files as it is running fine in PyCharm. Is it possible to tell python to include lib folder? I think since PyCharm is able to do it, it must be possible without changing the source.

Comment: This is because if you run python in the PyCharm's terminal it has different sys.path. Try running interactive python both in the PyCharm's terminal and in your normal terminal and then: `import sys` and `print(sys.path)`and compare the output.

Answer (score 0):

Improving on Saiful's answer, You can do the following which will allow you to run the your program from any working directory

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), "../"))
import lib.util1 as u1
```