# Python self-defined module not found

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a directory structure as follow:

```
evaluate.py
tools (folder)
   -- ngram.py
   -- bleu.py
```

In `bleu.py`, I import `ngram`. And, in `evaluate.py`, I import `tools.bleu`. However, an error occurs that `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ngram'`. Where did I do wrong? Thanks~

Comment: You say you made `ngram.py` and tried to import it, but it looks like you tried to import `gram`, not `ngram`, at least according to your error message. Typo?

Comment: can u rewrite your question by mentioning tree structure of directories. As like this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53760098/python-include-library-folder-when-running-from-command-line/53760336#53760336

Comment: @ShadowRanger Sorry, typo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you intend for `tools` to be a package, you'll need to change the modules within it to use either absolute imports or explicit relative imports when they are importing each other.

That is, you need to change `tools/bleu.py` to do either:

```
import tools.ngram     # or: from tools import ngram
```

Or:

```
from . import ngram
```

You should probably put an `__init__.py` file in the `tools` folder too (though it's not *strictly* necessary any more).

Comment: It works, thanks! What if I only want to import one function, say `get_ngram` from the `ngram.py` file?

Comment: I think you can use `from .ngram import get_ngram` for that. Note the dot preceeding the module name, which tells Python it's a relative import.

Comment: Just a note, while going for the complexities, just make sure you don't run into circular dependencies.